# is there any named regular expression capture for grep?

Tags: regex, bash

i'd like to know if its possible to get named regular expression  with `grep -P`(linux bash) from a non formatted string? well.. from any string

For example:
`John Smith www.website.com john@website.com jan-01-2001`
to capture as

```
$name
$website
$email
$date
```

but it seems I cant pass any variables from output?

`echo "www.website.com" | grep -Po '^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$' | echo $domain`

has no output

Comment: do `domain=$(echo Website.com | grep -Po ...`) ; echo $domain`. Good luck.

Comment: no. `grep` is a process. you are talking about environment propagation from child to parent. that's forbidden. instead, you can do `DATA=($your_line)`, then take `name=DATA[0]` so and forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no. grep is a process. you are talking about environment propagation from child to parent. that's forbidden.

instead, you can do

```
DATA=($your_line)
```

then take `name=DATA[0]` so and forth.

or another way using awk:

```
eval "`echo $your_line | awk '
    function escape(s)
    {
        gsub(/'\''/,"'\''\"'\''\"'\''", s);
        s = "'\''"s"'\''";
        return s;
    }
    { 
        print "name="escape($1);
        print "family_name="escape($2);
        print "website="escape($3);
        print "email="escape($4);
        print "date="escape($5);
    }'`"
```

the sense here is to propagate the info via stdout and eval it in the parent environment.

notice that, here, escape function will escape any string correctly such that nothing will be interpreted wrongly(like the evil of quotes).

following is the output from my jessie:

```
name='John'
family_name='Smith'
website='www.website.com'
email='john@website.com'
date='jan-01-2001'
```

if the family name is `O'Reilly`, the eval result will still be correct:

```
name='John'
family_name='O'"'"'Reilly'
website='www.website.com'
email='john@website.com'
date='jan-01-2001'
```

Comment: How can I use regex here? I need to make sure the value matches the pattern. Is there a way? Or I have to run additional check for every variable? For example in the next string 'website' is missing, then escape($3) becomes email instead of website

Comment: @Shirker oh yeah. that's the case, if your input data is not stable, things can be complicated. this is a short example of what you can do. basically the idea is print values to stdout, then eval. if there is a possibility that a field is missing or any other problems, it's better to use, say python, to apply more specific handling. but the procedure won't be much different than mine.

Comment: yeah, I think with python it would be easy. Time to start learning it

Comment: @Shirker it seems you know perl. it would do too. just pick your best tool

Comment: nope, i just read few tutorials and watched 30 videos. At least I have a picture

Comment: @Shirker if you decide to use python, have a look at `pipes` and `shlex` in 2.7, or `shlex` alone in 3.x.

Answer (score 4):

Grep is an independent command-line utility; it does not run inside of bash. So it couldn't create bash variables even if it wanted to.

However, bash has a regular expression matcher built-in. It's not a perl-compatible regex matcher, so it doesn't implement named captures. (To be precise, it matches Posix extended regular expressions, the same as `grep -E`.) But it does implement numbered captures.

You do regular expression matches with the `=~` operator inside of the `[[ ... ]]` compound command syntax. If the regular expression matches, then the expression succeeds, and the captures are inserted into the array variable `BASH_REMATCH`. `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` will be the entire matched substring, and the remaining elements, starting with `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`, will be the individual captures in order.

For example:

```
$ url=www.example.com
$ [[ $url =~ ^(www\.)?(.*) ]]
$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
www.
$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
example.com
```

Comment: Is there a way I can assign a number? for example `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` will always match ?([A-z]{1,} [A-z]{1,}) and `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` will be always ?(www\.)(.*) even these are misplaced? Or I should consider to use Perl instead?